# doesn't work an expression in angular ng-disabled

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new in Angular, so maybe I missing something. Does anybody know, what's wrong with expression state in such case:

The value 'isDisable.state' change in 'p' tag, but not in 'ng-disabled'. The button doesn't change it state to disabled.

Here is the plunk:http://plnkr.co/edit/zc8k9oCUxlMRCkZKjQa5?p=preview

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Example - example-example53-production</title>
  

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0-beta.1/angular.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myapp = angular.module('switcher',[]);
myapp.controller('switchState', function ($scope) {
      $scope.isDisable = {'state':false};
      $scope.toggle = function () {
        $scope.isDisable.state = !$scope.isDisable.state;
       
      }
});
</script>
</head>
<body ng-app="switcher">
<div ng-controller="switchState">
<button ng-click="toggle()">toggle</button>
 <button ng-disabled="{{isDisable.state}}">Disabled</button>
 <p>{{isDisable.state}}</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `{{}}`

```
ng-disabled="isDisable.state"
```

Comment: He's dead on. The ng-disabled directive expects an expression already, so by adding the {{ }}, you're just passing in the string value "true" or "false".
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled

Comment: omg, that was easy.. thanks a lot!
but what's the point with braces in ng-disabled in that way?

Comment: @Mike -- Certain Angular directives expect an Angular expression and some don't. Best to check the docs first, eventually you'll just memorize them :D

Comment: @tymeJV, yeah, you're right. must check the docs and need a nap ))